# Working form - how to plug in PHPMailer for attachment function only

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, attachment

I have my form setup and working perfect, however I need to add attachment functionality (only) to this.  I've reviewed several threads and tried implementing but with no luck.

I'm trying to add id='file-7'

HTML code:

```
<fieldset class="clean">
                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset class="percent-one-full">
                        <div class="box">
                        <input type="file" name="file-7[]" id="file-7" class="inputfile inputfile-6" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
                        <label for="file-7"><span></span> <strong><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/></svg> Upload file&hellip;</strong></label>
                        <input name="send" type="submit" class="button red" id="submit" onClick="MM_validateForm('name','','R','bandname','','R', 'email','','RisEmail','comments','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="SEND"/>
```

JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#cform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="images/nivo-preloader.gif" class="contact-loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

    $.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        bandname: $('#bandname').val(),
        osflow: $('#osflow').val(),
        hiddenDiv: $('#hiddenDiv').val(),
        hiddenDivv: $('#hiddenDivv').val(),
        hiddenDivvv: $('#hiddenDivvv').val(),
        hiddenDivvvv: $('#hiddenDivvvv').val(),
        hiddenDivvvvv: $('#hiddenDivvvvv').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#cform img.contact-loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#cform').slideUp('slow');
        }

    );

    });

    return false;

});

});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

print_r($_POST);
$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$_POST['bandname'];
$_POST['osflow'];
$_POST['hiddenDiv'];
$_POST['hiddenDivv'];
$_POST['hiddenDivvv'];
$_POST['hiddenDivvvv'];
$_POST['hiddenDivvvvv'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
//$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
exit();
}


if(trim($comments) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your message.</div>';
exit();
//} else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
//  echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter the verification number. </div>';
//  exit();
//} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
//  echo '<div class="error_message">The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
//  exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@example.net";
$address = "info@example.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'Decal Inquiry from ' . $name . '';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name. The additional message is as  follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_body = "Name: $name" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_body2 = "Email: $email" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_custom = "Band Name: $bandname" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_custom2 = "Interest In: $osflow" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_custom3 = "Drum Size: $hiddenDiv" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_custom3 = "Drum Head Color: $hiddenDivv" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_custom4 = "Mic Port Position: $hiddenDivvv" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_custom5 = "Banner Color: $hiddenDivvvv" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_custom6 = "Banner Size: $hiddenDivvvvv" . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_content .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file-7" . "\r\n";
$e_content = "Comments: $comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email at $email.";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_body2 . $e_custom . $e_custom2 . $e_custom3 .  $e_custom4 . $e_custom5 . $e_custom6 . $e_custom7 . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

// Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<div id='success_page'>";
echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, we've received your inquiry and will be in touch shortly.</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can't use PHPMailer _just_ for attachment functionality expecting to keep using mail()...

Comment: If you used two different mailers, you will have to different emails going out. It's like sending a letter at one post office and a box via UPS. You're sending out two different things. You can put the letter with the box and send them together via one carrier. In your case, you should stick to PHPMailer

Comment: ahhh, ok.  Thank you for the info, appreciate it!

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday, to which you received the same answers. You're still forging your from address, you're still vulnerable to header injection. Throw away your code and start again with one of the PHPMailer examples like [this one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).